# Not able to nest divs elemnets using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nested

In the starred code is the nested div elements, I have read XML file which has news articles. I want to read and add those to this nested format using jquery.

```
<div id="for-you-feed" class="container" style="justify-content: center;">

  <div class="row view-group " id="rowview">

    **
        <div class="item grid-group-item col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class=" thumbnail card border-light" style="width: 20rem; ">
                <div class="img-event ">
                    <img class="group list-group-image img-fluid " src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/74745223.cms " alt=" " />
                </div>
                <div class="caption card-body ">
                    <h4 class="group card-title inner list-group-item-heading ">
                        Hyderabad: Buses with same number plates seized</h4>
                    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text ">
                        The transport authorities, under the guidance of deputy transport commissioner Papa Rao, seized four buses that belo</p>
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div id="footer1" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">
                            <p class="lead ">
                                $21.000</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="footer2" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 ">
                            <a class="btn btn-success " href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com ">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    **
</div>
```

My code of jquery is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Frssfeeds%2F-2128816011.cms&api_key=mkzfaqsb5gtninv1pddoke81vwmjlyfiissiitvd", function(data, status) {
    //$("#rowview").empty();
    for (i in data.items) {
        console.log(data.items[i].thumbnail);
        console.log(data.items[i].title);
        console.log(data.items[i].link);
        console.log(data.items[i].description);

        console.log(data.items[i].description.slice(pos + 4));
        var pos = data.items[i].description.indexOf("</a>"),
            $divitem = $("</div>").attr('class', 'item grid-group-item col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12');

        var $divthumb = $("</div>").attr({ "class": 'thumbnail card border-light', style: 'width: 20rem' }),
            $divimg = $("</div>").attr('class', 'img-event  '),
            $imggrp = $("</img>").attr({ "class": 'group list-group-image img-fluid ', src: data.items[i].thumbnail }),
            $divcaption = $("</div>").attr('class', 'caption card-body'),
            $headcard = $("</h4>").text(data.items[i].title).attr('class', 'group card-title inner list-group-item-heading'),
            $paracard = $("</p>").attr('class', 'group inner list-group-item-text').text(data.items[i].description.slice(pos + 4)),
            $divrow = $("</div>").attr('class', 'row'),
            $divfooter1 = $("</div>").attr({ "class": 'col-xs-12 col-md-6', id: 'footer1' }),
            $lead = $("</p>").attr('class', 'lead').text('$21.000'),

            $divfooter2 = $("</div>").attr({ "class": 'col-xs-12 col-md-6', id: 'footer2' }),
            $atag = $("</a>").attr({ class: 'btn btn-success', href: 'http://www.jquery2dotnet.com' }).text("Add to cart");



        $("#rowview").append($divitem.append($divthumb.append([$divimg.append($imggrp), $divcaption.append([$headcard, $paracard, $divrow.append([$divfooter1.append($lead), $divfooter2.append($atag)])])])));

        // $($divthumb).append([$divimg, $divcaption]);
        //$($divimg).append($imggrp);
        // $(divthumb).append(divcaption);
        //$($divcaption).append([$headcard, $paracard, $divrow]);
        // $(divcaption).append(paracard);
        //$(divcaption).append(divrow);
        //$($divrow).append([$divfooter1, $divfooter2]);
        //$($divfooter1).append($lead);
        //$(divrow).append(divfooter2);
        // $($divfooter2).append($atag);

        // $(".view-group").append($divitem);


    }
  });
});
```

I'm not getting the response on my website.  I even tried the code in the comments, but didn't work.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(data.items.length)`?

Comment: the length is 10 bro

Comment: the data i have read is JSON not XML

Comment: The *data* you have is neither JSON nor XML (I'm guessing this was to a deleted comment?) - it's a javascript object which you're accessing as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code and it is working. Hope it helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sidebar demo</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="rowview"> </div>
 
 <script>
 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2Frssfeeds%2F-2128816011.cms&api_key=mkzfaqsb5gtninv1pddoke81vwmjlyfiissiitvd", function(data, status) {
   for (i in data.items) {
    console.log(data.items[i].thumbnail);
    console.log(data.items[i].title);
    console.log(data.items[i].link);
    console.log(data.items[i].description);
    console.log(data.items[i].description.slice(pos + 4));
    var pos = data.items[i].description.indexOf("</a>"),
     $divitem = $("<div>").attr('class', 'item grid-group-item col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12');

    var $divthumb = $("<div>").attr({ "class": 'thumbnail card border-light', style: 'width: 20rem' }),
     $divimg = $("<div>").attr('class', 'img-event  '),
     $imggrp = $("<img>").attr({ "class": 'group list-group-image img-fluid ', src: data.items[i].thumbnail }),
     $divcaption = $("<div>").attr('class', 'caption card-body'),
     $headcard = $("<h4>").text(data.items[i].title).attr('class', 'group card-title inner list-group-item-heading'),
     $paracard = $("<p>").attr('class', 'group inner list-group-item-text').text(data.items[i].description.slice(pos + 4)),
     $divrow = $("<div>").attr('class', 'row'),
     $divfooter1 = $("<div>").attr({ "class": 'col-xs-12 col-md-6', id: 'footer1' }),
     $lead = $("<p>").attr('class', 'lead').text('$21.000'),

     $divfooter2 = $("<div>").attr({ "class": 'col-xs-12 col-md-6', id: 'footer2' }),
     $atag = $("<a>").attr({ class: 'btn btn-success', href: 'http://www.jquery2dotnet.com' }).text("Add to cart");



    $("#rowview").append($divitem.append($divthumb.append([$divimg.append($imggrp), $divcaption.append([$headcard, $paracard, $divrow.append([$divfooter1.append($lead), $divfooter2.append($atag)])])])));

    // $($divthumb).append([$divimg, $divcaption]);
    //$($divimg).append($imggrp);
    // $(divthumb).append(divcaption);
    //$($divcaption).append([$headcard, $paracard, $divrow]);
    // $(divcaption).append(paracard);
    //$(divcaption).append(divrow);
    //$($divrow).append([$divfooter1, $divfooter2]);
    //$($divfooter1).append($lead);
    //$(divrow).append(divfooter2);
    // $($divfooter2).append($atag);

    // $(".view-group").append($divitem);


   }
    });
  });
 
 </script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```